# Heuristic Function for A* Algorithm on a Weighted Graph

Tags: python-3.x, a-star, heuristics

I'm doing an assignment for A* algorithm. I'm given a graph in a form of adjacency list, telling which node can go to which node along with the distances, the starting node, the ending node. For BFS and DFS, it was pretty straightforward by just using a queue and a stack respectively. For implementing A* algorithm, I'm also given a heuristic.csv file. However, the form of this heuristic file is odd for me. It has 3 columns, the node IDs, ID1, ID2, ID3. For each row, it informs the heuristic distance from ID1/ID2/ID3 from the current row's node ID.

```
nodeID, 26059364,418723472,123838209
26059364,100,200,300
26059376,400,500,600
...
...
```

For example, 100 is the heuristic distance between node 26059364 and node 26059364. I'm confused because what if I need the heuristic distance between a node that is not at the column node ID(26059364, 418723472, 123838209) since there are only 3 IDs there.

My current idea is to use that csv file and calculate the heuristic distance for every node (try to find the closest distance from node A to node B for every node A, B). However, I'm not sure if that is correct and the time complexity would be massive. Please provide me a possible algorithm to do so if possible, or another method that would work for completing the A* algorithn. Thanks.